# How to use 2 attributes of each JsonObject from a JsonArray in a ListView?

Tags: android, json, rest, listview, adapter

I send a request to my server , and it returns me JSONObject or a JSONArray
My JSONObject looks like :

```
    {
    "place":
    {
        "plAddress1": "15th Street of Republic",
        "plAddress2": null,
        "plAddress3": null,
        "plCity": "Lyon",
        "plCountry": "France",
        "plId": 2,
        "plState": "Rhone",
        "plZipcode": "69000"
    },
    "vComplementsValues":
    [
    ],
    "vDepth": 0,
    "vDiameter": 15,
    "vFunction": "function",
    "vId": "VREVN0000001",
    "vInstallationdate": "2000-05-23T00:00:00",
    "vLastlatitude": 44.9278,
    "vLastlongitude": 4.90465,
    "vMaxnbrofrevolutions": 5,
    "vOpeningdirection": 0,
    "vStatus": "OPEN",
    "vWheelDiameter": 30,
    "vWheelType": "3 branches"
}
```

With each object , I want to fill a ListView , and this ListView shows only the ID and the Status. I want to keep the other attributes , I will implement an OnClick to show all the information about the object.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: You're asking us to parse your `JSONArray` and all this without showing your effort. To cut my comment short, please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert JSONArray to ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440138/how-to-convert-jsonarray-to-listview)

Answer (score 0):

Here will be your code(if you have any question to declaration feel free to ask me in comment) :

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray("your_json"); // you already have this code
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                //suppose you have long id and int status
                long id = object.optLong("id"); //your id name in json
                int status = object.optInt("status"); //your status name in json

                YourType item = new YourType(id, status);
                items.add(item);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanges();
```

**Important** : if you have not long and int for your values, don't use methods like `getString`, use `optString` and so on instead

Comment: Thanks for the answer , my Id is a String ("VREVNXXXXXXX" where X are numbers). My second problem is that I want to show more details when i click on a result (like the status etc)

Comment: Sorry, maybe you missyndertood my comments, i meant "your_id_column", you will take your variables by "column_name" it the same for all objects, __t I want to show more details when i click on a result (like the status etc)__ what do you mean by that

Comment: Look my first post , I want to show only the id/status on my ListView , and then , if I click on a result , I want to show all the information.

Answer (score 0):

fill the list from json object.

```
   try {
         JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonArray);
         try {
         List<obj>listObj = new ArrayList<obj>();
         for(int i=0i<array.lenght;i++){
            JSONObject jobj= array.getJSONObject(i);
            if(jobj.getString("id")=!null&&jobj.getString("status")=!null){
            obj.setId(jobj.getString("id"));
            obj.status(jobj.getString("status"));
            }
            listobj.add(obj);
          }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


class obj {
String id;
String status;
}
```